# Python copy and paste path file from Windows Explorer into variable

Tags: python-3.x

I developed a software in Python3.4 which has as input a config file with a set of variables and some of them are paths.

I have a problem with the separator in the file path name.
I know I can put a "r" in front of the string or use the double backslash or the slash so to have a raw string, but because this software will be used by other users and the average one is just a "copy and paste" guy, I don't want they manipulate the file name.

So the users have just to copy from the Windows Explorer the file path and paste into the config file, something like:

```
path_variable = "C:\Users\home\room\table.txt"
```

and I want to write a function that modify it so can be used.

How can I do it? If I leave the string in this way I obtain an unicode error because of \U...

Thanks a lot,

Ciccio

**Update**

The config file is not a python file but just a .txt file within the variables and their values:

```
var_name = var_val
path_variable = "C:\Users\home\room\table.txt"
height = 20
plot_write_variable = ["y", "n"]
```

This is just a temporary solution until I finalize the GUI. This file must be really easy to understand and the software has to be used by people don't have any knowledge of Python or programming. The final user has just to change the variables value and click on the executable file to run the program and nothing else. For this reason I want to avoid as much as possible the use of any python command.

To read the config file I use this function:

```
import imp
def read_inputFile(path):
    file = open(path)
    variables = imp.load_source('data', '', file)
    file.close()
    return variables
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config files don't have to be written in Python.  You could use [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), which so far as I can tell does not interpret backslashes specially.

This may require some re-working of your logic for the config file.  Instead of importing the config file directly with an `import` statement, you would parse it with the `configparser` module.  You may also need to adjust the syntax of your config file to match what `configparser` is expecting.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I updated a bit my question to be more clear. I like the idea of `configparser`, but, as you say, I have to adjust a bit the syntax, is there a way, for now, to avoid it? Otherwise I move on `configparser`

Comment: @cicciodevoto: Your config file *is* a Python file.  If it wasn't, then `imp` wouldn't be able to load it.  If you don't like the full complexity of Python, then don't use it.

Comment: yes you are right it's a Python file, sorry for my mistake. Ok thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your users are "copy and paste" kind of guys, but you are having them paste file locations into a config file. I don't know your code, but if the config file is in python, you could add a line:

```
path_variable = input("Enter the path").replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

Python interprets `\\` as `\`, which fixes your problem

This solves the problem of them copy-pasting into the file, and instead prompts them for the filepath.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this is a nice solution to have a more interactive script, I will keep in mind for the future, but it's not really what I need now. I updated the question to be more clear.