# Python: How to change directory to a path copied and pasted from Windows Explorer

Tags: python, path, copy-paste, windows-explorer

On a Windows machine I am trying to write a scrip which would change the Python (I am using Anaconda Spyder 5.4) working directory to the directory of some files I am trying to feed to the script.

The path to the target folder is very long, probably more than 10 directories nested and I might need to change the path for subsequent operations, so doing it by hand would not be appropriate.

Hence, I would like to write a Python script which prompts the user for the path and then the user pasted the path he copied from Windows explorer.

For exemplification:

Windows Explorer path is: D:\Program\Anaconda\conda-meta

The problem is that Python treats some letters followed by backs lashes as special characters, so the string I read from the pasted Windows Explorer path is not valid.

I know that by replacing the back slashes with forward slashes would solve the issue, but manually doing that every time kind of defeats the point of programming.

I think a similar question has been asked here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867672/python-copy-and-paste-path-file-from-windows-explorer-into-variable](https://stackoverflow.com)

But I found no answer to my problem.

Thank you very much!

One way which works is reading the raw string as following:

```
import os

WinPath = r'D:\Program\Anaconda\conda-meta'
NewPath = os.fsencode(WinPath)
os.chandir(NewPath)
```

But this requires me writing the Windows Explorer path in the script, which I don't want. What I want is for the user to be asked to input the path by pasting. Something like:

```
import os

WinPath = input("Paste file path here:")

#somehow make it a raw string and encode it into the NewPath variable

os.chandir(NewPath)
```

But I have no idea how to actually do that.

I tried using the repr() function, but then I get an error saying the path is too long:

```
import os


WinPath = input("Paste file path here:")
WinPath = repr(WinPath)
NewPath = os.fsencode(WinPath)
os.chandir(NewPath)
```

Edit: @Matthias correctly indicated that the code should work fine, granted the os.chdir() function is properly called, which I tried right now on my personal PC and works.

Seems I don't properly understand the difference between input() and declaring a variable in the interpreter - I have tried to declare the WinPath in the interpreter as a test before writing the script and never actually made it to that step.

I guess the question can be closed.

Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: If you input the text you don't have to deal with backslashes. A raw string ist just something you use in the code to indicate that backslashes in this string definition should not be treated as an escape character. It should work as it is (of course you have to change `os.chandir` to the correct function).